# Reading/writing data in one azure gen2 storage account in multiple paths using multiple linked services in synapse notebook

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

Reading/writing data in one azure gen2 storage account in multiple paths using multiple linked services in synapse notebook. we can't read with single linked service as we have multiple SPN which has the access to all the paths.

Steps I followed to implement the same
1. Created a multiple linked service pointing to the gen2 storages using varies SPN1 , SPN2
**linked_service_name = 'ln_spn1_path_1'
spark.conf.set('spark.storage.synapse.linkedServiceName',linked_service_name)
spark.conf.set('fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type','com.microsoft.azure.synapse.tokenlibrary.LinkedServiceBasedTokenProvider')**

2. Created linked service ln_spn2_path_2 using spn 2 and pointing to the path2

   **linked_service_name = 'ln_spn2_path_2'
   spark.conf.set('spark.storage.synapse.linkedServiceName',linked_service_name)
   spark.conf.set('fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type','com.microsoft.azure.synapse.tokenlibrary.LinkedServiceBasedTokenProvider')

   ```
    mssparkutils.fs.ls("abfss://container@storaegaccount.dfs.core.windows.net/path2")**
   ```

If above both the commonds run in same synapse notebook so we will get the below error which ever we run later

**Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:mssparkutils.fs.ls. : java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: Operation failed: "This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.", 403, GET, AuthorizationPermissionMismatch, "This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission. RequestId:8853fd20-001f-0018-0347-bf3712000000 Time:2021-10-12T08:57:13.0513182Z"**

Can we read the data using to different linked services in same notebook?

Answer (score 0):

> UPDATE: I had tested on azure gen2 storage account in multiple paths using multiple linked services in synapse notebook.

Linked service: ADLSGen2_chepra with the notebook named Linked_service_name

[image]

Linked service: AzureDataLakeStorage_chepragen2 with the notebook named Linked_service_name

[image]

Note: Storage Blob Data Contributor: Use to grant read/write/delete permissions to Blob storage resources.

If you are not assigning "Storage Blob Data Contributor" to other synapse users, they will be not able to access the data from ADLS gen2 due to the lack of permission on the storage account.

[image]

If they try to access data from ADLS gen2 without the "Storage Blob Data Contributor" role on the storage account, they will receive the following error message:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:mssparkutils.fs.ls. : java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: Operation failed: "This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.", 403
```

[image]

Reference: [Grant permissions to workspace managed identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/security/how-to-grant-workspace-managed-identity-permissions).

Comment: I am able to read the data individually like two linked service in two synapse notebook but when I run the both in one notebook I get the above error on linked service which ever I executed later. It looks like the spark config set is not able to overwrite the linked service.  How to handle this?

Comment: I had tested with multiple linked service in a single notebook and it works as excepted. Please check the updated answer.

Comment: @ram did you ever figure out the root cause here? Inside of a Notebook the data writes correctly, however as soon as I run the Spark notebook through a Pipeline it does not and I have tried adding rhe Synapse Workspace as Data Contributor and Owner on the Storage Account AND ACLs